# Browse contents of external disk while it is not connected

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-management, search-indexing

I want to index the contents of an external disk, so I can later browse it while it is not connected to my PC.

**Is that possible? How?**

I can index for searching it with, e.g., locate32 (outstanding!), but I do not know how to browse it.
Perhaps there is a solution via PowerShell or the like.

**EDIT**:
I have just found a few utils (something portable would be ideal for me, as I do not have admin rights) which *may* be good for what I need.
This question is at the overlap between SuperUser and Software Recommendations.
Answers in both styles may work.

http://www.anderssoftware.com/ocdb/

https://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/CD-DVD-Tools/Portable-CD-Offline.shtml

http://www.cdfinder.de/

https://www.wincatalog.com/

Comment: So what **is** your external disk connected to?

Comment: @DavidPostill - At the time of browsing, it would be not connected. See edited OP.

Comment: I don't know if this works for you, but try [TREE - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/tree.html) and save the output to your PC.

Comment: You have given little explanation as to what kind of behavior you expect. Davids approach would be an easy one but if you expect full Windows Explorer browsing you might find that hard to achieve.

Comment: Why not do `dir/s > c:\output.txt` and then scan through the output? You can throw in other /options to change the output style of dir

Comment: @DavidPostill - TREE is good, but it does not show file sizes (important for me) / attributes (somewhat less important).

Comment: @Seth - Ideally, full "Windows Explorer browsing" is what I want. But less versatile options may be good.

Comment: @spikey_richie - dir/s indeed gets essentially all information I need, but in a hard-to-browse format.